# Does something that glows red emit more heat than something equally hot that isn't glowing?

Tags: thermodynamics, visible-light, material-science, infrared-radiation

Watching carbon-ceramic brakes on race cars on YouTube got me started. Heat something and its temperature will go up, the hotter is gets, the higher the frequency of the energy it emits, and so something that is hot enough to glow red is going to be emitting higher energy photons and more energy. But what about flux density? Could a different material with a lower temperature be emitting more energy? (Let's assume similar areas / volumes) Does everything start glowing at the same temperature (let's exclude things that don't survive high temperatures)?

Comment: Just because something contains heat does not mean it is emitting it.  If it emitted the same amount of heat it would glow at the same frequency.

Comment: Please read the [Wikipedia article on emissivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emissivity). It's all in there. If not, please ask more specific.

Answer (score 1):

A material with a lower temperature can emit more energy than a higher temperature material, but the emission has to be non-thermal.

Any material in local thermodynamic equilibrium will emit radiation, if that material is sufficiently optically thick (ie. opaque, photons must scatter off many atoms before making it to the surface) then the material radiates like a black-body and the radiation will have a thermal spectrum, the Planck Function:
$$ 
B_\nu(\nu,T) = \frac{2 h \nu^3}{c^2} \left[ \exp\left(\frac{h\nu}{k_B T}\right)-1\right]^{-1}\ .
$$
This gives the power per unit surface area per unit frequency emitted by a blackbody. The frequency is $\nu$, the temperature is $T$, $h$ is Planck's constant, $c$ is the speed of light, and $k_B$ is Boltzmann's constant.

This spectrum peaks at a particular frequency that is linearly dependent on the temperature $\nu_{peak} \propto T$.  It is an increasing function of temperature, so a hotter (black body) material emits more energy at every frequency. The colour we associate with a hot object is simply the frequency at which the emission is peaked.  Two black-bodies with the same temperature will have identical spectra, and appear the same colour.

The total power per surface area emitted by a black body is given by the Stefan-Boltzmann Law:
$$
F = \sigma_{SB} T^4\ .
$$
This increases *very* strongly with temperature.  A hot object with a thermal spectrum emits a lot more energy than a cool object with a thermal spectrum, every time.

However, not everything emits thermally!  LEDs, for instance, have a very non-thermal spectrum. So do fluorescent lights and lasers.

So, your answer: if the materials are emitting thermally, then the hotter object will always emit more energy per surface area.  If they are not emitting thermally (an IR laser for instance), it's anyone's game!

Comment: "Two black-bodies with the same temperature will have identical spectra, and appear the same colour." A material with a lower temperature can emit more energy than a higher temperature material, but the emission has to be non-thermal.

Comment: Previous comment is wrong. It should have said: "Two black-bodies with the same temperature will have identical spectra, and appear the same colour." That answers my main question, but this "A material with a lower temperature can emit more energy than a higher temperature material, but the emission has to be non-thermal." confuses me. What other kind of energy could it emit besides thermal? Thermal radiation is just another word for  electromagetic radiation, isn't it?

Comment: @CharlesPergiel I tried to address this near the end but perhaps I wasn't clear.  Thermal radiation is a particular type of electromagnetic radiation, emitted because of the temperature of the object.  Other objects (like LEDs, X-rays, microwave ovens, radio towers) emit electromagnetic radiation, but do so non-thermally.  An x-ray machine, for instance, runs an electrical voltage over a piece of tungsten, which causes it to emit x-rays. To emit x-rays thermally the machine would have to be millions of degrees!  Non-thermal radiation can (in principle) have any spectrum you like.